# Sharing google map V2 with polyline drawn on the map (Reusable)

Tags: android, share, google-maps-api-2, google-polyline

*Hi, I am new here. So if I have posted my question in the wrong place or any mistake, please do enlighten me. I have more or less browse through many sites searching for an answer but I could not find anything.*

Let me briefly explain about how my Android apps will work:
1. There's one part of my apps, it will track the location of the user via Wi-Fi and GPS.
2. It tracks the distance traveled, speed, time taken and etc.
3. Now I planned to add in another feature in, which is:

-> I want to share the route with the map which the user has ran through to Social networks where another user can press into it and the apps will automatically receive the route and map which previously ran by the first user so that he/she can challenge the first user by running the same route as the first one's route (guided by the polylines drawn on the map). Then the apps will be able to track the second user, and a New polyline will be drawn on the route to track his/her progress. (distance traveled, duration and polyline drawn on the Google map)

**Ques: How am I suppose to share the map together with polylines which are accessible by others.**

Comment: Are you talking about screenshot of the map? Have you tried any coding , logic, roadmap etc ? Plz let us know.

Comment: Not exactly is the screenshot. You see, there are some 'map' links which you can press into it through Google Maps or any GPS applications. It can give you the direction, etc.

Now, I wanted to share the route that I've ran to others. So when they press into the 'route' that I've shared, they can see which route I've ran and they can use it to challenge me by running the same route with lesser time.

Comment: You may want to improve the question by provinding pointers of what have you done and wht you are trying to achieve. basically, formatting of the question,

Comment: Ohh, alright alright. Thanks for the simple guidance, bro. Will try to be more precise. I really don't know how to put the question into words. It's something that I really don't know. I hope I will find out the answer soon and post it here if I do not get any answer I needed. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: You may want to look at this section about [How to ask on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have a server side for this as well, so if a user runs, the result will be uploaded to it. You should generate a unique ID for every run like this, and store it connected to the data needed to be stored (distance, speed, etc), and only share a URL from your app, and let the server handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Well, will try working on it.

One more thing, hmm. What do you mean by sharing URL from my app. How do I share the URL from the map? Does the URL carries the polyline I drawn on my map?

Comment: I meant like the app uploads the data to the server and share only a URL that points to it, like "www.myidea.com/travels/..../mytravel12345"